# Python3: import a long string (JSON) from another file

Tags: json, python-3.x, import

This is the original file_1.py. It works.

```
session_token = xxxxxxxxxx

body = """{
    ....
    ....
    "session": "%s"
}""" % session_token
```

Now I want to move **body = """{  ....  }"""** (except **% session_token**) to file_2.py (for example, a new parameter named json_string)

Thus, file_1 becomes:

```
import file_2
session_token = xxxx

body = file_2.json_string % session_token
```

It will return error. How to fix?

Comment: Please post your error and your file structure.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug this is to start the script in interactive shell mode:

```
python -i file_1.py
```

Then you can just check the values of body, session etc. You can even call `dir()` and check your environment dictionary:

```
python>> dir()
# results in something like: [__builtins__, ..., body, session]
```